# idt_table undefined! warning when compiling kernel module

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, interruption

I'm trying to use `gate_desc *idt_table` in a kernel module. The `set_trap_gate()`  function defined in desc.h uses this pointer. In desc.h is also a definition : `extern gate_desc idt_table[]`.

I tried different things:

- use `idt_table` in my module without definition or affectation
- affect `idt_table` with my (valid) `idt_table` address
  I get either an `id_table` undefined warning during compilation or incomplete type for `idt_table`.
- creating a new var named for instance `gate_desc *it = (gate_desc *)@;` And copy the `set_trap_gate`, `set_gate`, `write_idt_entry`, `pack_gate` functions from sched.h to my module file (renaming them, and using it instead of `idt_table`). This compiles fine but when inserting my module I get an unknown symbol in module (ret -1) error.
  (there is no reference in my module to idt_table, and the functions I use from sched do use my variable).

I tried to see where in the files included by sched.h was defined `idt_table`, but couldn't find it!

Does someone know how I could use, the idt_table pointer from sched.h (affecting it with the corrct address) or create a new pointer?

Comment: It's not safe do do this sort of operation from a kernel module, and will not work on SMP systems anyway as you'd be modifying the table of only one CPU core (and they're not necessarily guaranteed to be shared). Using it is restricted to kernel initialization (that's why it's marked `__init`). What exactly is it you're trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could implement a non-init-section `set_trap_gate()` via:

```
void set_trap_gate(int n, void *addr)
{
    struct { uint16_t lim; struct desc_struct *idt_table; }
        __attribute__((packed)) idt;
    __asm__ ("sidt %0" : : "m"(idt) : "memory");
    _set_gate(idt.idt_table + n, 15, 0, addr);
}
```

But that'd be CPU-local, i.e. it's not guaranteed to modify any other IDT but the one of the CPU it's running on. Also, it might fall foul of writeprotected memory.

What exactly is it you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I want to use the in desc.h provided functions like set_trap_gate to implement a simple version of debug register rootkit (for an academic work as student). For this I need to replace the do_debug handler in INT1 in idt